What is "Chrome File Utilities" process and why does it slow down my system?
It is a process spawned by Chrome.
I was compressing a folder on my drive unrelated to anything chrome has to do with and it was sucking up my CPU and making winrar unresponsive?
What does that process do? Why does it slow down my computer? And what are the consequences of killing it? (It sure is behaving like malware!)

what is the actual process name and path? you probably won't find anything out without additional information.

That is the actual name. Or, well "Utility: Chrome File Utilities". System-wise all chrome processes are named "Google Chrome" and the path points to chrome.exe, somewhat obviously. This is the name in chrome's own Task manager.

As it can be seen here, this name is used by IDS_UTILITY_PROCESS_FILE_UTILITY_NAME translation string. You can then based on that find that it's used by FileUtilService. That leads to chrome/services/file_util folder which has the following description:

The FileUtilService is used to perform operation on archives in a sandboxed utility process. It currently provides the following operations:

Creation of a ZIP archive from a collection of file handles
Extraction of a single file from a .TAR or .TAR.XZ archive
Analysis of ZIP, RAR, DMG, and 7Z archives for Safe Browsing

Code in //chrome/services/file_util is expected to run within a restrictive utility process sandbox. Code in //chrome/services/file_util/public/ can be run from privileged processes, including the browser process.

I am not sure as to why it'd bother checking something completely unrelated to Chrome. I don't seem to experience similar behavior on latest Chrome either. This might be a bug and I would report this behavior to Chromium developers instead of trying to get around the lag it causes.

Ah, thank you. So it does have something to do with working on archives. I would normally submit a bug, but I have absolutely no confidence it will ever be looked at, much less fixed. If it misbehaves again it will simply be mercilessly killed. I tried replicating it, but I'm not sure how. Maybe it matters which folder I'm archiving from. ¯\(ツ)/¯
